# Array after an element is > 0 change all elements to that value until next non zero value

Tags: arrays, swift, enumerate

I have an array that is for example

```
[0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 55.0, 22.0, 0.0, 55.0]
```

How can I change the element with 0 value if the previous value > 0? so

```
[0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 55.0, 22.0, 0.0, 55.0]
```

becomes

```
[0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 22.0, 22.0, 55.0]
```

I have tried the following and it removes the zeros and nothing else.

```
func weightArrayRemovedZero(array: [Double])->[Double]{

 var arrayToAlter = [Double]()

 for(index,item) in array.enumerated() {

   print("The \(item) is at index:\(index)")

   if item == 0.0 {
     if index > 0 && index < array.count - 1 {

       if array[index - 1] != 0.0 {
         let nonZeroElement = array[index - 1]
         arrayToAlter.append(nonZeroElement)
       }
     }


   } else {
     arrayToAlter.append(item)
   }
 }

 return arrayToAlter
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` seems to be the natural approach to me:

```
var last = 0.0
let mapped = values.map { elem -> (Double) in
    last = elem > 0.0 ? elem : last
    return last
}
```

Generally speaking, `map` is your go to when you want to change one collection into another collection with a one-to-one element mapping.

Comment: You beat me to this, @David Berry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
var array = [0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 55.0, 22.0, 0.0, 55.0]

array.enumerated().forEach {
    array[$0] = $1 == 0 &&
        array.indices.contains($0 - 1) &&
        array[$0 - 1] > 0 ? array[$0 - 1] : $1
}

print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
var array = [0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 55.0, 55.0, 22.0, 0.0, 55.0]

for i in array.indices {
    if i == 0 { continue }
    if array[i] == 0  && array[i-1] != 0 {
        array[i] = array[i-1]
     }
}
```

// [0, 0, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 22, 22, 55]